# Prove that the upper integral is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f : [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb R$ be a function defined as
> $$
> f(x) 
> = \begin{cases}
>    x & \text{if x is rational} \\
>    0 & \text{if x is irrational}
>    \end{cases}
> $$
> Prove that the upper integral is greater than or equal 1/2, that is $$ \bar{\int_{0}^{1}} f \geq \frac{1}{2}$$

I think we have to somehow show that $1/2$ is a lower bound for the upper Darboux sum of $f$, and from then on we can use the definition of the upper integral to conclude what we want to prove. But I’m unable to do it.

Let’s take a partition $$P= \{ 0, x_1 , x_2 \cdots \frac{1}{2}, \cdots 1\}$$. Now, for any interval $[x_{i-1} , x_i]$, $x_i \gt \frac{1}{2}$, we have $$ M_i = sup\{f(x) : x \in[x_{i-1}, x_i]\} \gt \frac{1}{2}$$ That is we have for every interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$, $x_i \gt 1/2$ :
$$
M_i \gt 1/2 \\
M_i(x_i - x_{i-1}) \gt 1/2(x_i - x_{i-1}) $$ Now, summing it over the $i’s$, keeping in mind that only those $i’s$ are allowed such that $x_i \gt 2$ we will get
$$
\sum_{i} M_i (x_i -x_{i-1}) \gt 1/4$$

But I’m unable to get any further than this, I don’t even think my method will lead me to anywhere worth going. Please give me some hint on this, don’t give full solution.

Comment: Because the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, you can see that for any subdivision, the upper Darboux sum of $f$ is the same as the upper Darboux sum of the function $g(x)=x$.

Comment: @Mindlack Yes. And so we can have a partition with equal widths and rational points, will that help us in any way?

Comment: No, I'm saying that for *any* partition, the upper Darboux sum is that of the function $g(x)=x$, so is greater than the integral of $g$ which is $1/2$.

Comment: I agree mindlack's argumentation.

Comment: I'm confused the answers below seem to be in conflict, one saying the integral limits to a $1/2$, the other saying the integral is always greater than $1/2$.

Comment: @JamesArathoon That limit one doesn’t say that upper integral of $f$ is 1/2 rather it says that the integral of $g(x)=x$ is 1/2 and upper darboux sum is always greater than the integral and that’s why the inequality.

Comment: @Knight: If a different integral technique is used that always underestimates the Riemann Sum, except in the limiting case they become equal; isn't it just as valid to prove via this other integration technique (assuming absolute convergence) that the integral is always $\le \frac{1}{2}$. If this underestimated sum happens to be conditionally convergent, then the order that sum progresses becomes important in determining the final value. Do you have to prove absolute convergence from above and below the Riemann Limiting Sum for the upper Darboux sum to give unique and meaningful results?

Comment: @JamesArathoon I just have to prove that the upper integral is greater/equal to 1/2, because integral doesn’t even exist for this function.

Comment: @Knight: Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @JamesArathoon You’re most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have established that any upper sum is equal to
\begin{equation*}
\sum_i x_i(x_i - x_{i - 1})
\end{equation*}
you can use *intuition* about the function $f(x) = x$, but still proceed with rigorous, elementary analytical techniques. This sum is like a sum of rectangles, and you want to show it's at least the sum of the trapezia below it that form a triangle together.
\begin{align*}
\sum_i x_i(x_i - x_{i - 1})
 &= \sum_i [\tfrac 12 (x_i + x_{i - 1}) + \tfrac 12 (x_i - x_{i - 1})](x_i - x_{i - 1}) \\
 &= \sum_i [\tfrac 12 (x_i^2 - x_{i - 1}^2) + \tfrac 12 (x_i - x_{i - 1})^2)]
\end{align*}
Can you take it from there?

Comment: I’m sorry but I cannot take it further? Help me a little more. (By the way your avatar is very nostalgic :-) )

Comment: @Knight, no problem! The second term in the sum is always positive, so you can just ignore it to find a lower bound, leaving you with $\sum_i \tfrac 12(x_i^2 - x_{i - 1}^2)$. This is what is called a telescoping sum. If you write out the first few terms, you will see that almost all of the sum will cancel. Say if the sum was up to $i = n$, we are just left with $\tfrac 12 (x_n^2 - x_0^2)$. But recall that the $x_i$ partition $[0, 1]$, so  we know what $x_0$ and $x_n$ are. (Ignoring the second term is like ignoring the extra small triangles at the top of the rectangles). (Yay Pokemon `:)`)

Comment: Okay, so we will get $$ U(f,P) = \frac{1}{2}+ \sum_{i} \frac{1}{2} (x_i - x_{i-1} )^2 $$ and thus it means that $U(f,P)$ will always be greater than 1/2. Thank you so much. (Psyduck! Psyduck! Did you use the intelligence of Psyduck ? :-) )

Answer (score 2):

For your function, for **any** partition you have $M_i=x_i$. So the upper sum is
$$\sum_ix_i(x_i-x_{i-1}).
$$
This is a Riemann sum for the function $g(x)=x$, so the limit is $1/2$.

Comment: I agree with that, but this question appears in Patrick Fitzpatrick’s Advanced Calculus before he teaches how to calculate the integrals, so I thought we have to make use of only inequalities not the integrals.

Comment: You already got that in Izaak's answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Marty for your efforts and for being kind :-)

Comment: My pleasure. Note that $M_i=x_i$ requires a small argument when $x_i$ is irrational.

Comment: Yes I know it requires some argument requiring convergence. Would you please please explain it (if you don’t mind) ?

Comment: I'd rather you try :)

Comment: I got it Marty. Let’s say we have an interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ and we know that $$M_i = sup\{f(x) : x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]$$. Now, let $y$ be the greatest rational number less than $x_i$ then we are tempted to say $M_i = f(y) =y$ but due to “density” of rationals we can say that “there exist a rational number between $y$ and $x_i$” and let that number be $x$, we have $y \lt x \implies f(y) \lt f(x)$ and hence $y$ is not an upper bound. So, we can show that $x_i$ is a least upper bound and hence proved.

Comment: Kind of. Here is a more precise argument. Given any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $y\in\mathbb Q$ with $x_i-\varepsilon<y<x_i$. So $f(y)-y>x_i-\varepsilon$, which shows that $\sup\{f(x):\ x\in [x_{i-1},x_i]\}\geq x_i-\varepsilon$. As you can do this for all $\varepsilon>0$, the equality follows.