# Prove that the total weighted mean sum of $n$ rationals within $[0,1]$ tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: integration, elementary-number-theory, summation, riemann-integration, rational-numbers

This question has been raised because of my initial confusion concerning [this question on the upper Darboux sum of $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727631/prove-that-the-upper-integral-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-frac12):

> Again consider $f : [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb R$ be a function defined as
> $$
> f(x) 
> = \begin{cases}
>    x & \text{if x is rational} \\
>    0 & \text{if x is irrational}
>    \end{cases}
> $$

However in this case I don't want to consider this function as continuous and integrate it, I want to consider it a discrete function consisting of an infinite number of discrete rational fractions and create a suitable weighted mean sum over the interval $[0,1]$.

I wish to calculate the limit of the following weighted mean sum as $n$ tends to infinity:

$$S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum _{m=2}^n \frac{1}{m-1}\left(\sum _{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{k}{m}-\frac{\sigma _1(m)-m-1}{m}\right)\tag{1}$$

where $\sigma _1(m)$ is the sum of all the divisors of $m$ and $(\sigma _1(m)-m-1)$ is equivalent to [Chowla's function](https://oeis.org/A048050) for $m>1$

Now using the approximation $$S_n <\frac{1}{n}\sum _{m=2}^n \frac{1}{m-1}\sum _{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{k}{m}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2 n}$$

in the limit $n \to \infty$

$$S_{n \to \infty} < \frac{1}{2}$$

However is it seems that in actual fact for my sum $(1)$

$$S_{n \to \infty}=\frac{1}{2}$$

which would mean

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum _{m=2}^n \left(-\frac{\sigma _1(m)-m-1}{(m-1)m}\right)=0 \,.\tag{2}$$

**However I'm not sure how to prove this last statement and the relation of the weighted sum formula (1) to the notional Riemann Integral over rational $f$ assuming continuity?**

Presumably  I need to first obtain an upper bound somehow for Chowla's function for $m>1$

The discrete plot of

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum _{m=2}^n \left(\frac{\sigma _1(m)-m-1}{(m-1)m}\right) \tag{3}$$

is shown below:

[image]

Compared with a discete plot below using a bounding function from [Jeffrey Lagarias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) assuming the Riemann Hypothisis is true:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum _{m=2}^n \frac{H_m+e^{H_m} \log \left(H_m\right)-m-1}{m (m-1)}$$

[image]

I'm not sure the bound needs to be this good to prove $(2)$, even though it seems a better bound to (3) might conjecturally be

$$\frac{1}{e\, n}\sum _{m=2}^n \frac{H_m+e^{H_m} \log \left(H_m\right)-m-1}{m (m-1)}$$

**As a further note**; numerically it appears that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum _{m=1}^n \frac{\sigma _1(m)}{m}\approx \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

which may help with finding a bounding function for $\sigma _1(m)$.

The conjecture of course is that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum _{m=1}^n \frac{\sigma _1(m)}{m}= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

**Update 2:**

I can get a very good approximation to

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum _{m=2}^n \frac{\sigma _1(m)}{m (m-1)}$$

using for example

$$\frac{\pi ^2}{6 n} \sum _{m=2}^n \frac{\left(m-\frac{1}{10}\right)^2}{m^2(m-1)}$$

where $\frac{1}{10}$ is a constant added to help give a bounding curve fit. However how do I justify making use of this (admittedly in a sightly modified form) or similar approximation, to prove the limit in $(2)$.